# Checking if Serial Port is Open

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to check if a serial port is open, if it is, then I'll close it. I'm not sure how check if the port is or isn't open.

Basically, something like this..

```
SerialPort port1 = new SerialPort("COM4",9600,Parity.None,8);
port1.Open();

if(/*port is open*/)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Port is open");
    port1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "check if port has been opened by another process"? Or you want to check does your code actually opened it?

Comment: If the port is already open, the .Open call will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check if connection is open use the class attribute `IsOpen`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen(v=vs.110).aspx

```
if (port1.IsOpen)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Port is open");
    port1.Close();
}
```

Comment: I believe that only checks if that instance of `port1` is open. It does check if other instances on the same com port or another process has it open. The OP was not clear if he was wanting to check the `port1` instance or if he was checking for other processes having the port open.